# sqlite login only reading last password

Tags: php, database, sqlite, authentication, passwords

I'm trying to create a login which only needs PASSWORD to access. I've got this.

```
/* Validates the login form data, checks if username and password are provided
@return bool Login form data check success state */
    private function checkLoginFormDataNotEmpty() {
        if (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) { return true; }
        elseif (empty($_POST['user_name'])) { $this->feedback = "Username field was empty."; }
        elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) { $this->feedback = "Password field was empty."; }
        return false; } // default return


/* Checks if user exits, if so: check if provided password matches the one in the database
@return bool User login success status */

    private function checkPasswordCorrectnessAndLogin() {
        // remember: the user can log in with username or email address
        $sql = 'SELECT user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
                FROM users
                WHERE user_name = :user_name OR user_email = :user_name
                LIMIT 1';
        $query = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':user_name', $_POST['user_name']);
        $query->execute();

        // Btw that's the weird way to get num_rows in PDO with SQLite:
        // if (count($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) == 1) {
        // Holy! But that's how it is. $result->numRows() works with SQLite pure, but not with SQLite PDO.
        // This is so crappy, but that's how PDO works.
        // As there is no numRows() in SQLite/PDO (!!) we have to do it this way:
        // If you meet the inventor of PDO, punch him. Seriously.
        $result_row = $query->fetchObject();
        if ($result_row) {
            // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check password
            if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {
                // write user data into PHP SESSION [a file on your server]
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                $_SESSION['user_is_logged_in'] = true;
                $this->user_is_logged_in = true;
                return true; }
            else { $this->feedback = "Wrong password."; } }
        else { $this->feedback = "This user does not exist."; }
        // default return
        return false;
    }
```

So I removed the things related to 'user_name' until I got this:

```
/* Validates the login form data, checks if username and password are provided
@return bool Login form data check success state */
    private function checkLoginFormDataNotEmpty() {
        if (!empty($_POST['user_password'])) { return true; }
        elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) { $this->feedback = "Password field was empty."; }
        return false; } // default return


/* Checks if user exits, if so: check if provided password matches the one in the database
@return bool User login success status */

    private function checkPasswordCorrectnessAndLogin() {
        // remember: the user can log in with username or email address
        $sql = 'SELECT user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
                FROM users
                LIMIT 1';
        $query = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        // Btw that's the weird way to get num_rows in PDO with SQLite:
        // if (count($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) == 1) {
        // Holy! But that's how it is. $result->numRows() works with SQLite pure, but not with SQLite PDO.
        // This is so crappy, but that's how PDO works.
        // As there is no numRows() in SQLite/PDO (!!) we have to do it this way:
        // If you meet the inventor of PDO, punch him. Seriously.
        $result_row = $query->fetchObject();
        if ($result_row) {
            // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check password
            if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {
                // write user data into PHP SESSION [a file on your server]
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                $_SESSION['user_is_logged_in'] = true;
                $this->user_is_logged_in = true;
                return true; }
            else { $this->feedback = "Wrong password."; } }
        else { $this->feedback = "This user does not exist."; }
        // default return
        return false;
    }
```

PROBLEM: It works, but only with the first password in sql database.

Any solution please? I would thank you so so much :(

Comment: yeah. what do think `LIMIT 1` does?

Comment: Christ! i don't know but tried to change it and it doesn't work, and it works with LIMIT 1 when including 'user_name'

Comment: @njzk2 could you suggest another answer please? this is draving me crazy... it seems it doesn't have to do with limit... peoples is downvoting my comment :'(

Comment: Your first script actually looks right, you have to search the user first and afterwards can get the password hash from the found row. What message do you get? An often made mistake is, that the database field holding the "user_password_hash" is too short, so you would get back a shortened hash which doesn't match the password of course. Make sure the field is of length `varchar(60)` or even better `varchar(255)` to be future proof.

Comment: checked, it was already varchar(255) @martinstoeckli anyway thankyou for your suggestion. I'm trying to create a login wich ONLY requires password (no need to write username). The database has 3 columns: user, passwordhash and email. With my modified code I can access with the password of the first user, but not with the rest of them. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR ADVICE

Comment: sorry @martinstoeckli, the message I get when using passwords which are not the first is "wrong password"

Comment: @Kathlyn - Unfortunately it is not possible to savely store the passwords and to make them searchable, the problem is the salt and the slowness of a safe hashing algo. Are you sure you don't need any security?

Answer (score 1):

@njk2 has already identified the issue. Here's why, check out your query:

```
 SELECT user_name, user_email, user_password_hash FROM users
```

This will pull a list of ALL the users in probably insert order.  If you tack on `LIMIT 1` then it grabs only the first row from that set. This will be only the first password in the database.

Looking at this much only, I don't think it makes any sense to eliminate usernames AND still want to identify a user (with `$_SESSION['user_name']`). **I would strongly advise against it**, and frankly this was already not the most secure setup to begin with.

Ignoring that, this approach firstly has a **potential for conflicts** (what happens if two users have the same password, "pass1234"? How can you tell who they are just from their password?).

Even if you banned conflicts (no users can have the same password) - then you still made it **vastly easier to hack into** (you don't need to know a user's username AND password, just to try a list of passwords).

Advice aside, you could just theoretically search by password hash:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
            FROM users
            WHERE user_password_hash = :password
            LIMIT 1';
    $query = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':password', password_hash ($_POST['user_password']));
```

Comment: Actually ignore the parts I had about salting, password_hash will do that for you as long as your using a reasonably up-to-date version of PHP.

Comment: I'm a primary school teacher. Though I consider your advice really interesting for further projects, I do not think my 6-year-old pupils hack into a classmate account even if his password is "banana" and classmate's "apple". Morover, your apprecieated suggestion to my code doesn't work. Anyway I thank you guys to waste your time trying to solve an out of phase educator.

Comment: It would be great to add salting but I don't have knowledge enough. I was working with md5 until yesterday and text-file database. Today I found this, something called one-file-login which uses sqlite database.Thought it would be easier to modfy in order to achieve my purpose but it seems it isn't :'( Thanks anyway :) (THE LIMIT WAS NOT THE ISSUE)